# How to remove an owner from a team in Teams without removing it from member list?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I use GraphAPI to add a user as both member(POST `/groups/{id}/members/$ref`) and owner(POST `/groups/{id}/owners/$ref`) into a team in Microsoft Teams.
Then I use "DELETE `/groups/{id}/owners/{userId}/$ref`" to remove this user from owners list. I expect the user is still in members list, but looks like it was removed from members list as well.
How to remove a user only from owners list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Known issue: when DELETE /groups/{id}/owners is called, the user is also removed from the /groups/{id}/members list. To work around this, we recommend that you remove the user from both owners and members, then wait 10 seconds, then add them back to members.

You need to use this workaround at the moment. And keep an eye on Graph API documents. I think it will be fixed sooner or later.

Comment: do yo mean I need to remove the user from owners list and then add it back into members list?

Comment: yes. you are right. please wait 10 secs before adding it back.